# Quick Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort

I did not see this algorithm from anywhere and did it myself, just saw how the Quick Sort works, this is in Java and the problem is, it is sorting well and good for number of values upto 6, it hangs on values for more than 6. or there could be some other problem I don;t know.
Here is the code-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter number of elements= ");

        int x, a[];
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = Integer.parseInt(z.next());
        a = new int[x];

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter element #"+(i+1)+"= ");
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(z.next());
        }

        QuickSort(a, 0, x-1);

        System.out.print("A= ");
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
    }

    public static void QuickSort(int a[], int low, int high){
        if(low >= high)
            return;

        int l = low + 1, h = high, flag = 0, temp;

        while(l <= h){
            if(a[low] >= a[l]){
                ++l;
                ++flag;
            }
            if(a[low] <a [h]){
                --h;
                ++flag;
            } else if(flag == 0){
                temp = a[l];
                a[l] = a[h];
                a[h] = temp;
                ++l;
                --h;
            }
        }

        temp = a[low];
        a[low] = a[h];
        a[h] = temp;
        QuickSort(a, low, h-1);
        QuickSort(a, h+1, high);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Is there a reason that `Arrays.sort()` will not work for you?

Comment: @cjstehno presuambly it's a homework assignment

Comment: I think this is a perfect opportunity to learn to use a debugger. It will let you step through the code and find out where exactly things are going wrong.

Comment: As a programming question, I think this is "too localized".

Comment: Whether or not it is homework, I think the objective is for the OP to understand Quick Sort, not just to sort an array.

Comment: It might help if you wrote your code more readably too.

Comment: @OP, does your name mean happiness in Turkish?

Comment: @ Siddharth Mutluru :  Why not use junit and find out yourself-- along with debugger as NPW wrote above?

Comment: @Antimony:How do I do that?

Comment: @vikingsteve: It's Gautam Buddha's given name (original name).

Comment: It's a homework assignment. I don't hate using imports XD

Comment: @Sid among other things, I'd put a space between if statements that aren't part of the same else if, put braces around the body of ifs and whiles, and move variable declarations onto separate lines in most cases. Apart from that, `flag` should have been a boolean since you're only using it for a T/F value, and it should have been declared inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to set `flag` back to 0 in your inner loop, thus causing it to get into an infinite loop.

Adding the line `flag=0;` after `while(l<=h){` makes it work. Though you should really learn to write code that isn't a completely illegible mess. Not only will that let people help you more easily, it will even make bugs like this easier to spot yourself.

Also, you should really learn basic troubleshooting skills before asking for help. I didn't even need to use a debugger, I just added a couple of print statements to see where it was getting stuck.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Shame I made such a mistake. Just wanted to know what you really meant about the thing that I need to learn to write a code that ain't a complete illegible mess. I thought the code was well written ;( I learned though Lynda Basic Java. Do you mean I should be adding comments? or is there a problem with the code structure as it is or the approach? From what my teacher wrote I made the QuickSort() shorter and easier to look upon :(